# I am retriving the List if country name and state name frome database using store procedure in C# Here are the snaps of my code asp.net MVC

Tags: c#

This is the view page of my application

```
<div class="container">
@foreach (var item in Model)
{

    var temp = item.CountryId;
    <ul>
        @if (temp == item.CountryId)
        {
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CountryName)
            temp = item.CountryId;
            foreach (var states in item.State)
            {
                <li>@states.StateName</li>
            }
        }
        else
        {
            temp = 0;
        }

    </ul>
}
```

I am getting this type pf result but I want the same country name only once
so if any one can help me what should changes i  have to make in my code ???

Australia
  Malborne

India
  Gujarat
  mumbai

India
  Gujarat
  mumbai

UK
 London
 Ontario

i want to display only this

Australia
  Malborne

India
  Gujarat
  mumbai

UK
 London
 Ontario

This is controller code and usp_country_select() is my procedure name

```
var country = db.usp_country_select().Select(c => new CountryViewModel
        {
            CountryId = c.CountryId,
            CountryName = c.CountryName,
            State = db.States.Where(x => x.CountryId == c.CountryId).Select(x => new StateViewModel
            {
                StateId = x.StateId,
                StateName = x.StateName
            }).ToList()
        }).ToList();
        return View(country);
```

store procedure as follows

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_country_select]
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT 
        c.CountryId,
        c.CountryName,
        s.StateName
    FROM 
        Country AS c
    INNER JOIN [State] AS s ON s.CountryId = c.CountryId
    ORDER BY c.CountryName 
END
```

Comment: I can't find the question !
Please, Edit your question and add more information.

Comment: Please update the title of your question to reflect the problem you are trying to solve and remove the irrelevant parts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do a groupBy

This is with LinQ C#

```
var groupedCountryList = _myCountries.GroupBy(u => u.CountryId)
    .Select(grp => grp.ToList())
    .ToList();
```

also SQL

```
  SELECT COUNT(Id), Country 
      FROM Customer
     GROUP BY Country
```

Hope helps you.

Answer (score 0):

You are putting the CountryId in temp and then check if temp equals item.CountryId, which will always be true.

```
var temp = item.CountryId;
<ul>
    @if (temp == item.CountryId)
```

Comment: I know but i want to make changes there what will the condition i have to replace